# Efficient way of pulling all data from a mongo collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo collection that has good amount of data in that, for my usecase I want to get all the data from the collection and keep in in-meomory.

Currently we are using JPA query findAll() to pull all the data which works fine in most of the time but sometimes we see cursor not found exception.

Below is the exact exception message

`"org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException", "message" : "Cursor 7250434402800140524 not found on server mgs-stage.com:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$CursorNotFound: Cursor 7250434402800140524 not found on server mgs-stage.com:27017"`

Is there any other better/efficient way to pull the data from the collection ?

Comment: What have you tried and why does it not work for you?

Comment: @vsfDawg I used findAll() to get all the data but it seems due to high volume of data ,sometimes it fails with cursor not found exception.